# Message "npm WARN config `--global`, `--local`

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

May i know what is the cause for this issue and how to try overcome it at initial install itself?

Answer (score 0):

This warning is about the deprecated `--global` and `--local` options.

If you were using one of these options to launch a NodeJS application, replace it by `--location=global` OR `--location=local`.